# Почему в моей анимации, transform: scaleY(), начинает действовать сразу после запуска анимации?

Tags: html, css3, анимация, css-animation

Ядро должно растягиваться по оси X после того, как дойдет до 600 пикселей. Я выставил кейфрейм с разницей в один процент до финального, чтобы ядро растянулось очень быстро, будто от удара об стену. Но по какой-то причине, оно начинает растягиваться с самого первого кадра. Почему так и как исправить?

```css
@keyframes cannon
{
  0%
  {
  background-color: #333300;
  height: 50px;
  width: 150px;
  transform:translateX(-15px);
  }
  4%
  {
    transform: rotate(-50deg);
    background-color: #333300;
    height: 50px;
    width: 150px;
  }
  6%
  {
    transform: rotate(5deg);
    background-color: #333300;
    height: 50px;
    width: 150px;
  }
  12%
  {
    transform: rotate(-3deg);
    background-color: #333300;
    height: 50px;
    width: 150px;
  }
  20%
  {
    transform: rotate(1deg);
    background-color: #333300;
    height: 50px;
    width: 150px;
  }
  21%
  {
    transform: rotate(0deg);
    background-color: #333300;
    height: 50px;
    width: 150px;
  }
  100%
  {
    transform: rotate(0deg);
    background-color: #333300;
    height: 50px;
    width: 150px;
  }
}

@keyframes anima
{
  0%
  {
    background-color: #006600
  }

  99%
  {
    left: 600px;
    background-color: #006600
  }
  100%
  {
    left: 600px;
    transform: scaleY(3);
    background-color: #006600
  }


}
#cannon
{
  position: absolute;
  top: 50px;
  left: 50px;
  animation-name: cannon;
  animation-duration: 6s;
  margin: 0;
  z-index: 1;

}

#ball
{
  height: 30px;
  width: 30px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  animation-timing-function: linear;
  position: absolute;
  top: 61px;
  left: 75px;
  animation-name: anima;
  animation-duration: 6s;
  z-index: 0;

}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>

<div id="cannon"></div>
<div id="ball"></div>
<div id="wall"></div>
<div id="floor"></div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```css
@keyframes anima
{
  0%
  {
    background-color: #006600
  }

  80%
  {
    transform: scaleY(1);
    left: 600px;
    background-color: #006600
  }
  100%
  {
    left: 600px;
    transform: scaleY(3);
    background-color: #006600
  }
}
```